# How to setup prometheus, grafana and blackbox_exporter for ping lost rate

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to use prometheus, grafana and blackbox_exporter to monitor my servers by ping(icmp).  We faced network unstable recently, but my setting can not show alert.  I'm wonder should I use 'probe_duration_seconds' or other probe method?

grfana setting Metrics: probe_duration_seconds and Panel data source is prometheus

blackbox.yml:

```
modules:
  icmp:                                                                                                                                                                                       
    prober: icmp                                                                                                                                                                              
    timeout: 5s                                                                                                                                                                               
    icmp:                                                                                                                                                                                     
      protocol: "icmp"                                                                                                                                                                        
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
```

prometheus.yml:

```
global:                                                                                                                                                                                       
  scrape_interval:     15s                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  external_labels:                                                                                                                                                                            
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'                                                                                                                                                                
scrape_configs:                                                                                                                                                                               
  - job_name: 'blackbox'                                                                                                                                                                      
    scrape_interval: 5s                                                                                                                                                                       
    metrics_path: /probe                                                                                                                                                                      
    params:                                                                                                                                                                                   
      module: [icmp] #ping                                                                                                                                                                    
    static_configs:                                                                                                                                                                           
      - targets: ['192.168.1.29']                                                                                                                                                            
        labels:                                                                                                                                                                               
          group: 'env A'                                                                                                                                                                   
      - targets: ['192.168.2.185', '192.168.3.185', '192.168.4.185']                                           
        labels:                                                                                                                                                                               
          group: 'env B' 
    relabel_configs:                                                                                                                                                                          
      - source_labels: [__address__]                                                                                                                                                          
        regex: (.*)(:80)?                                                                                                                                                                     
        target_label: __param_target                                                                                                                                                          
        replacement: ${1}                                                                                                                                                                     
      - source_labels: [__param_target]                                                                                                                                                       
        regex: (.*)                                                                                                                                                                           
        target_label: instance                                                                                                                                                                
        replacement: ${1}                                                                                                                                                                     
      - source_labels: []                                                                                                                                                                     
        regex: .*                                                                                                                                                                             
        target_label: __address__                                                                                                                                                             
        replacement: 127.0.0.1:9115
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`probe_success` will be 1/0 depending on whether the ping succeeded.

Comment: In my case, I manual typing the 'ping 192.168.2.185', and got 25% lost. Is there better method?

Comment: After skim the source code of blackbox_explorer, I found it seems only have two variable could audio, probe_success and probe_duration_seconds

Comment: I found all the values of probe_success are zeros, so it is also useless. :(

Comment: @DanielYCLin Then it sounds like ping from your exporter to your target isn't possible. You may want to run additional exporters to get metrics from other locations to understand from where your site might not be available. If you don't want to run them yourself, you can use my service: https://latency.at